# using haproxy to forward multiple ports to same backend server, how can I avoid multiple backend/frontend phrase?

Tags: haproxy

I'm trying to use haproxy to forward multiple ports to the same backend server. Right now I had to write multiple frontend and backend phrase.

I need to forward port 80 to backend port 80, port 81 to backend port 81, and so forth until port 89.

```
frontend front_80
  bind *:80
  default_backend back_80

backend back_80
  server server1 1.1.1.1:80 maxconn 50000

frontend front_81
  bind *:81
  default_backend back_81

backend back_81
  server server1 1.1.1.1:81 maxconn 50000

... same for port 82 to port 89 ...
```

Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: @t.niese It's not. I need port to port forwarding, e.g 80 to 80, 81 to 81. However the link your provided does not do that, it listens on multiple ports but forward to the same port, e.g 80 to 80, 81 to 80, ...

Answer (score 2):

yes, port is optional on the `server` line and when missing it uses port from frontend to connect to backend, so this should work:

```
frontend front
  bind *:80
  bind *:81
  bind *:82
(...)

default_backend back

backend back
  server server1 1.1.1.1
```